# Configure Apache to use multiple VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-7

I'm trying to configure Apache 2.4 on a Windows server.

I need two different ["Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/mass.html) :

- a "simple" on to serve folders from the "projects" hard drive,
- and another with more options, for projects that use the Symfony php framework.

To differenciate the two, I thought about using the URL *"example"* to serve the folder "example", and *"example.symfony"* to serve the folder "example" using the symfony vhost config.

Here's my *httpd-vhosts.conf* file :

```
# symfony virtual hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.symfony:80
    VirtualDocumentRoot "E:\%1\web"

    <Directory "E:\%1\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    Alias /sf "E:\%1\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf"
    <Directory "E:\%1\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>



# other virtual hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *:80

    VirtualDocumentRoot "E:\%0"

    <Directory "E:">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        IndexIgnore .git
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration, both example and example.symfony use the same  settings. I'm guessing that Apache prefers the `ServerAlias` "`*:80`", more encompassing ?

What I've tried :

- using `ServerName` instead of `ServerAlias`, but it doesn't allow the * wildcards.
- changing the order of the vhost definitions, but this doesn't change a thing.
- writing `<VirtualHost *.symfony:80>`, but this is invalid, Apache says *"Could not resolve host name .symfony -- ignoring!"*

Comment: Please read [about] and be educated as to our scope. Windows7 development environments and WAMP are not topical here.

Comment: I get your point, but how does the fact that it is a development machine change the problem ? There are multiple questions on serverfault about vhosts configuration, and I thinks this particular issue could interest others.

Comment: This wouldn't be a question for Stack Overflow as it's really not related to programming. Server config questions are fine here. If you haven't received a lot of attention perhaps you could place a bounty on the question.